# how to bind dynamic json data to html using java script or angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have Json data ,product keys are dynamically changed, By using this product keys we are trying to bind this data to html

json:

```
{
        "ProductIdProperties": [
            {
                "productId": "890e5b4ceb9842c9bd8d8a01094b1e5f",
                "ProductKeys": [
                    ".Not Covered in Warranty",
                    ".Warranty Summary",
                    "Machine Dimensions.Color",
                    "Machine Dimensions.Dimension",
                    "Machine Dimensions.Weight",
                    "Ports/Slots.Other Ports",
                    "Ports/Slots.Multi Card Slot",
                    "Ports/Slots.VGA Port",
                    "Ports/Slots.HDMI Port",
                    "Ports/Slots.RJ45 LAN",
                    "Ports/Slots.Mic In",
                    "Ports/Slots.USB Port",
                    "Power.Battery Cell",
                    "Power.Power Supply",
                    "Power.Battery Backup",
                    "Communication.Bluetooth",
                    "Communication.Wireless LAN",
                    "Communication.Ethernet",
                    "Audio.Sound",
                    "Audio.Speakers",
                    "Audio.Internal Mic",
                    "Input.Keyboard",
                    "Input.Pointer Device",
                    "Input.Web Camera",
                    "Graphics.Graphic Processor",
                    "Display.Screen Type",
                    "Display.Resolution",
                    "Display.Screen Size",
                    "Platform.System Architecture",
                    "Platform.Operating System",
                    "Optical Disk Drive.Optical Drive",
                    "Optical Disk Drive.Read/Write Speed",
                    "Storage.HDD Capacity",
                    "Storage.RPM",
                    "Storage.Hardware Interface",
                    "Memory.System Memory",
                    "Memory.Memory Slots",
                    "Memory.Expandable Memory",
                    "Processor.Cache",
                    "Processor.Clock Speed",
                    "Processor.Brand",
                    "Processor.Chipset",
                    "Processor.Variant",
                    "Processor.Processor",
                    "General1.Model ID",
                    "General1.Lifestyle",
                    "General1.Model Name",
                    "General1.Brand",
                    "In the Box.Sales Package"
                ],
                "imageUrls": [
                    "/images/Chrysanthemum.jpg"
                ],
                "ProductProperties": {
                    "Sales Package": [
                        "Laptop",
                        "User Guide and Manuals"
                    ],
                    "General1": {
                        "Brand": "ssssssssssssss",
                        "Model Name": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                        "Lifestyle": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                        "Model ID": "rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr"
                    },
                    "Processor": {
                        "Processor": "hjj",
                        "Variant": "khj",
                        "Chipset": "khjhj",
                        "Brand": "hjh",
                        "Clock Speed": "kj",
                        "Cache": "jh"
                    },
                    "Memory": {
                        "Expandable Memory": "jkh",
                        "Memory Slots": "hj",
                        "System Memory": "hj"
                    },
                    "Storage": {
                        "Hardware Interface": "h",
                        "RPM": "jh",
                        "HDD Capacity": "jh"
                    },
                    "Optical Disk Drive": {
                        "Read/Write Speed": "jh",
                        "Optical Drive": "jh"
                    },
                    "Platform": {
                        "Operating System": "jkhkj",
                        "System Architecture": "hkj"
                    },
                    "Display": {
                        "Screen Size": "hkj",
                        "Resolution": "hjh",
                        "Screen Type": "h"
                    },
                    "Graphic Processor": "kj",
                    "Input": {
                        "Web Camera": "kj",
                        "Pointer Device": "hkjh",
                        "Keyboard": "h"
                    },
                    "Audio": {
                        "Internal Mic": "hkj",
                        "Speakers": "hj",
                        "Sound": "hh"
                    },
                    "Communication": {
                        "Ethernet": "j",
                        "Wireless LAN": "hj",
                        "Bluetooth": "h"
                    },
                    "Power": {
                        "Battery Backup": "hh",
                        "Power Supply": "h",
                        "Battery Cell": "h"
                    },
                    "Ports/Slots": {
                        "USB Port": "hh",
                        "Mic In": "Yes",
                        "RJ45 LAN": "Yes",
                        "HDMI Port": "Yes",
                        "VGA Port": "Yes",
                        "Multi Card Slot": "mmmmmmmmmmm",
                        "Other Ports": [
                            "Headphone Jack ",
                            "Audio Jack"
                        ]
                    },
                    "Machine Dimensions": {
                        "Weight": "1111111",
                        "Dimension": "2222222",
                        "Color": "3333333333"
                    },
                    "": {
                        "Warranty Summary": "44444444444",
                        "Not Covered in Warranty": "5555555555555"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I have Json data ,product keys are dynamically changed, By using this product keys we are trying to bind this data to html
java script:

```
for (var prop in ProductProperties)
    {
    alert(prop);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var arr={
    "ProductIdProperties": [
        {
            "productId": "890e5b4ceb9842c9bd8d8a01094b1e5f",
            "ProductKeys": [
                ".Not Covered in Warranty",
                ".Warranty Summary",
                "Machine Dimensions.Color",
                "Machine Dimensions.Dimension",
                "Machine Dimensions.Weight",
                "Ports/Slots.Other Ports",
                "Ports/Slots.Multi Card Slot",
                "Ports/Slots.VGA Port",
                "Ports/Slots.HDMI Port",
                "Ports/Slots.RJ45 LAN",
                "Ports/Slots.Mic In",
                "Ports/Slots.USB Port",
                "Power.Battery Cell",
                "Power.Power Supply",
                "Power.Battery Backup",
                "Communication.Bluetooth",
                "Communication.Wireless LAN",
                "Communication.Ethernet",
                "Audio.Sound",
                "Audio.Speakers",
                "Audio.Internal Mic",
                "Input.Keyboard",
                "Input.Pointer Device",
                "Input.Web Camera",
                "Graphics.Graphic Processor",
                "Display.Screen Type",
                "Display.Resolution",
                "Display.Screen Size",
                "Platform.System Architecture",
                "Platform.Operating System",
                "Optical Disk Drive.Optical Drive",
                "Optical Disk Drive.Read/Write Speed",
                "Storage.HDD Capacity",
                "Storage.RPM",
                "Storage.Hardware Interface",
                "Memory.System Memory",
                "Memory.Memory Slots",
                "Memory.Expandable Memory",
                "Processor.Cache",
                "Processor.Clock Speed",
                "Processor.Brand",
                "Processor.Chipset",
                "Processor.Variant",
                "Processor.Processor",
                "General1.Model ID",
                "General1.Lifestyle",
                "General1.Model Name",
                "General1.Brand",
                "In the Box.Sales Package"
            ],
            "imageUrls": [
                "/images/Chrysanthemum.jpg"
            ],
            "ProductProperties": {
                "Sales Package": [
                    "Laptop",
                    "User Guide and Manuals"
                ],
                "General1": {
                    "Brand": "ssssssssssssss",
                    "Model Name": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                    "Lifestyle": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                    "Model ID": "rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr"
                },
                "Processor": {
                    "Processor": "hjj",
                    "Variant": "khj",
                    "Chipset": "khjhj",
                    "Brand": "hjh",
                    "Clock Speed": "kj",
                    "Cache": "jh"
                },
                "Memory": {
                    "Expandable Memory": "jkh",
                    "Memory Slots": "hj",
                    "System Memory": "hj"
                },
                "Storage": {
                    "Hardware Interface": "h",
                    "RPM": "jh",
                    "HDD Capacity": "jh"
                },
                "Optical Disk Drive": {
                    "Read/Write Speed": "jh",
                    "Optical Drive": "jh"
                },
                "Platform": {
                    "Operating System": "jkhkj",
                    "System Architecture": "hkj"
                },
                "Display": {
                    "Screen Size": "hkj",
                    "Resolution": "hjh",
                    "Screen Type": "h"
                },
                "Graphic Processor": "kj",
                "Input": {
                    "Web Camera": "kj",
                    "Pointer Device": "hkjh",
                    "Keyboard": "h"
                },
                "Audio": {
                    "Internal Mic": "hkj",
                    "Speakers": "hj",
                    "Sound": "hh"
                },
                "Communication": {
                    "Ethernet": "j",
                    "Wireless LAN": "hj",
                    "Bluetooth": "h"
                },
                "Power": {
                    "Battery Backup": "hh",
                    "Power Supply": "h",
                    "Battery Cell": "h"
                },
                "Ports/Slots": {
                    "USB Port": "hh",
                    "Mic In": "Yes",
                    "RJ45 LAN": "Yes",
                    "HDMI Port": "Yes",
                    "VGA Port": "Yes",
                    "Multi Card Slot": "mmmmmmmmmmm",
                    "Other Ports": [
                        "Headphone Jack ",
                        "Audio Jack"
                    ]
                },
                "Machine Dimensions": {
                    "Weight": "1111111",
                    "Dimension": "2222222",
                    "Color": "3333333333"
                },
                "": {
                    "Warranty Summary": "44444444444",
                    "Not Covered in Warranty": "5555555555555"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
var k=arr.ProductIdProperties
for(var i in k)
{
 var ke=(k[i].ProductKeys );  
    for(var j in ke)
    {
        console.log(ke[j]);
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RjG24/)

Comment: The values must mach and bind with product properties that is
"ProductKeys": ["Machine Dimensions.Color"] match with "ProductProperties": {"Machine Dimensions": {
                    "Weight": "1111111",
                    "Dimension": "2222222",
                    "Color": "3333333333"
                }, the result will be 3333333333